# Are most Uber drivers unqualified to operate a vehicle for hire?

Tags: licensing, driving, regulations

When applying for a commercial drivers license many life saving and valuable knowledge is to be learned. Commercial classes in the USA ranges to Class D in some States which is a car and to Class A,B, and C recognized Federally in all States. Commercial endorsements can include **passengers**, triples, hazmat etc.

The (Class D non-commercial = **Private passenger**, regular operator) a common drivers license and is technically invalid when driving people commercially for pay, but most most Uber and others drivers are not qualified according to the regulations.  Why is this regulation not upheld or ignored federally in the US? Is this the same in other countries?

Comment: Questions "why law is such and such" is politics and offtopic here.

Comment: The question from the headline seems to be asking whether the law applies in this situation, which would be pretty on-topic, I'd think.

Comment: @Greendrake I hope this is better what do you think?

Comment: I think the question that would be on-topic here is "Are Uber drivers legally required to have a commercial license?" I have a feeling that this may turn out to not be as clear-cut as you seem to think.  But even if it turns out that such a requirement exists, the question "why is it not enforced?" would be off-topic.  Adding in "other countries" would tend to make the question too broad, so I'd leave that out.

Comment: So your original title would have been a fine question.  The problem was that in the body of the question, you took it for granted that the answer was "yes", and turned it into a different (and off-topic) question about why this purported requirement was not enforced.

Comment: To get started, https://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/registration/commercial-drivers-license/drivers suggests that federal law only requires a commercial (class A, B or C) license when transporting 15 passengers or more.  Individual states could have other requirements; for instance, [New York](https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/nys-driver-license-classes) appears to have a special Class E license that taxi (and Uber?) drivers must have.  So it may be hard to give a specific answer unless you restrict your question to a particular state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems to be based on some false assumptions.

As far as I can tell:

#### There is no federal requirement for an Uber driver to have a class A, B or C license.

Just because they are commonly called "commercial" licenses, it does not follow that every kind of commercial driving necessarily requires you to have one.

The US Department of Transportation has a [website](https://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/registration/commercial-drivers-license/drivers) describing what kinds of driving require these license types.

> Class A: Any combination of vehicles which has a gross combination weight rating or gross combination weight of 11,794 kilograms or more (26,001 pounds or more) whichever is greater, inclusive of a towed unit(s) with a gross vehicle weight rating or gross vehicle weight of more than 4,536 kilograms (10,000 pounds) whichever is greater.
>
> Class B: Any single vehicle which has a gross vehicle weight rating or gross vehicle weight of 11,794 or more kilograms (26,001 pounds or more), or any such vehicle towing a vehicle with a gross vehicle weight rating or gross vehicle weight that does not exceed  4,536 kilograms (10,000 pounds).
>
> Class C: Any single vehicle, or combination of vehicles, that does not meet the definition of Class A or Class B, but is either designed to transport 16 or more passengers, including the driver, or is transporting material that has been designated as hazardous under 49 U.S.C. 5103 and is required to be placarded under subpart F of 49 CFR Part 172 or is transporting any quantity of a material listed as a select agent or toxin in 42 CFR Part 73.

A typical Uber driver operating a typical passenger car (say, 5 passengers and 4000 pounds) would not fall into any of these categories.

#### Some states do require an Uber driver to have a special kind of license; others do not.

For example, [New York](https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/nys-driver-license-classes) has a Class E license, which for-hire drivers are required to have.  (Ordinary people typically get a Class D license instead.)

On the other hand, consider Colorado.  You can read about Colorado license classes [here (PDF)](https://www.sos.state.co.us/CCR/GenerateRulePdf.do?ruleVersionId=35).  Most ordinary people get a Class R license, and there is no indication that driving a passenger car for hire requires anything other than this.

#### In states where such requirements do exist, it appears that Uber verifies that its drivers do indeed have the appropriate license.

For instance, [here](https://www.uber.com/drive/new-york/get-a-license/) is Uber's page for prospective New York City drivers.  It explains that you have to get a Taxi & Limousine Commission (TLC) license, as well as a Class E driver's license.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm saying you not supposed to be transporting people with Class D for profit then its not for private use

Comment: @Muze: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "Class D".  That seems to be state-specific (for example, Colorado has no such thing as a "class D license").  But the point is that, at least in some states, there actually isn't any rule against using a "regular" driver's license to transport people for profit.  Such licenses are not restricted to "private use" in your sense of the word.